# How to find pattern in an Arraylist of coordinates?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, arraylist, jbutton

I hava class called Cell which has two properties x and y which extends JButton. Here is the code for that.

```
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            private int x;
            private int y;

            public Cell(int x, int y) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;

                String cellCoord = x + "," + y;
                JLabel cellLbl = new JLabel(cellCoord);
                this.add(cellLbl);
                this.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
            }

            public int getx() {
                return x;
            }

            public int gety() {
                return y;
            }

            public void setx(int x) {
                this.x = x;
            }

            public void sety(int y) {
                this.y = y;
            }
```

There is another class called Grid, that is used to create the 20x20 Grid which extends JPanel.

```
    public class Grid extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private ArrayList<Cell> cells;
        private int width = 20;
        private int height = 20;

        public Grid() {
            cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
        }

        public void drawGrid() {
            this.setLayout(new GridLayout(width, height, 5, 5));
            this.setBackground(Color.RED);

            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                    Cell cell = new Cell(i, j);
                    cells.add(cell);
                }
            }
            for (Cell c : cells) {
                this.add(c);
            }

        }

        public void refreshGrid() {
            this.removeAll();
            this.repaint();

            for (Cell c : cells) {
                this.add(c);
            }
        }

        public ArrayList<Cell> getCells() {
            return cells;
        }

        public void setCells(ArrayList<Cell> cells) {
            this.cells = cells;
        }

        public void changeCell(Cell c) {
            for (Cell cell : cells) {
                if (cell.getx() == c.getx() && cell.gety() == c.gety()
                        && cell.getBackground() != Color.black ) {
                    cell.setBackground(c.getBackground());
                    refreshGrid();

                }

            }
        }

        public Cell validateCell(int x , int y){
            Cell tmp = new Cell(x,y);
            for(Cell cell : this.cells){
                if(cell.getx() == x && cell.gety() == y){
                    tmp = cell;
                }
            }
            return tmp;
        }
```

How can I find a way to create a method which checks for the winner. Basically other functionality is already done like changing the turn of the player and changing the color of the button selected according to the player move (Each player can select one of the cell and change it to a color, it is really similar to collect 4 but the pattern of the colored button is a bit different).

The user could win if there are 9 buttons which are in a pattern which checks the North , North East, East, SouthEast, South, SouthWest, West, NorthWest of each colored cell. If some how 9 colored cells are connected with the same color the user wins.

Here is an example of a valid pattern where the ones that are highlighted with a yellow circle are connected to each other to form the pattern. The one with the red circle is the last cell that was dropped in this case the program noticed that there are 11 cells with the same color which means it exceeded the 9 matching rule , thus having a winner.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't the first player win every time ? There are 9 directions to link a block to another, there's no way to block the first player by placing one block per turn

Comment: The player could also use a special power which disables the cells , he has two chances of doing this in each game hence the player two could block player one from winning. 

It looks something like this 

[Image](http://i.imgur.com/Q3le8AX.jpg)

Comment: Ok, apart from this, what you need is using a graph traversal algorithm and count the number of nodes in the graph.

Comment: I'll check that out, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to maintain the game status and update that once a player  marks a cell.
 i don't think that performance is a concern for this kind of 2D game.so no need to go for a optimized complex algorithm.

```
class Cell
{

  // other codes

  public boolean isAdjacent(Cell cell)
  {
    int xDiff = cell.getX() - x;
    int yDiff = cell.getY() -y;
    if(xDiff>=-1 && xDiff<=1 && yDiff>=-1 && yDiff<=1)
    {
       return true;
    }
    return false;

  }
}
```

Introduce a new class to track cell blocks which is adjacent.

```
public class Block
{    
  private List<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();

      public boolean canMerge(Cell cell)
      {
        if (cells.isEmpty())
        {
          return true;
        }
        else
        {
          for (Cell existingCell : cells)
          {
            if (existingCell.isAdjacent(cell))
            {
              return true;
            }
          }
        }
        return false;
      }

      public void merge(Cell cell)
      {
        cells.add(cell);
      }

      public void merge(Block block)
      {
        cells.addAll(block.getCells());
      }

      public List<Cell> getCells()
      {
        return cells;
      }
}
```

Then new class to maintain the Game status

what you have to call markCell method once user click on a cell

```
public class GameStatus
{
  HashMap<Integer,List<Block>> players = new HashMap<Integer, List<Block>>();

  public boolean markCell(Cell cell,int player)
  {
    int count = 0;
    List<Block> blocks = players.get(player);
    if(blocks==null)
    {
      // this is the first cell mark by this player
      blocks = new ArrayList<Block>();
      Block block = new Block();
      block.merge(cell);
      blocks.add(block);
      players.put(player,blocks);
    }
    else
    {
      Block alreadyMergedToThisBlock = null;
      ArrayList<Block> shouldBeRemovedList = new ArrayList<Block>();
      for (Block block : blocks)
      {
        if(block.canMerge(cell)) // cell is adjacent to a block
        {
          if (alreadyMergedToThisBlock==null) // this is the first block we found which is adjacent to the given cell
          {
            block.merge(cell);
            count = block.getCells().size();
            alreadyMergedToThisBlock = block;
          }
          else
          {
            // we have already merge given cell to block,but this block also adjacent to the given cell.
            // that means two blocks can be merged together and this block can be removed once it is merged to the previous one
            alreadyMergedToThisBlock.merge(block); 
            count = alreadyMergedToThisBlock.getCells().size();
            shouldBeRemovedList.add(block);
          }
        }
      }
      blocks.removeAll(shouldBeRemovedList);
    }

    return count>=9;

  }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to add more statements in the  isAdjacent(Cell cell) to check for diagonal cases ?

Comment: no, same column means xDiff = 0, yDiff=+ or - 1, same row means xDiff = + or - 1 and yDiff =0, diaggonal means xDiff= + or - 1 and yDiff =+ or -1. then all combinations will be covered by that method.